# Creating new column based on an existing column value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame that has an existing column with airport names, and I want to create another column with their abbreviations.

For example, I have an existing column with the following values:

```
SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, CA US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, CA US
SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US
```

I would like to create a new column with their associated abbreviations, e.g SEA, MIA, and SFO. I was thinking I can use for loop to achieve that, but I am not so sure how to code it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 2 sample approaches:

1. using a dict and a UDF
2. using a second DataFrame to join with

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, StringType

s = """\
SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, CA US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, FL US
SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, CA US
SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US"""

abbr = {
    "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT": "SEA",
    "MIAMI INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT": "MIA",
    "SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT": "SFO",
}

df = spark.read.csv(sc.parallelize(s.splitlines()))

print("=== df ===")
df.show()

# =================================
#  1. using a UDF
# =================================
print("=== using a UDF ===")
udf_airport_to_abbr = udf(lambda airport: abbr[airport], StringType())
df.withColumn("abbr", udf_airport_to_abbr("_c0")).show()

# =================================
#  2. using a join
# =================================
# you may want to create this df in some different way ;)
df_abbrs = spark.read.csv(sc.parallelize(["%s,%s" % x for x in abbr.items()]))
print("=== df_abbrs ===")
df_abbrs.show()
print("=== using a join ===")
df.join(df_abbrs, on="_c0").show()
```

Output:

```
=== df ===
+--------------------+------+
|                 _c0|   _c1|
+--------------------+------+
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US|
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US|
+--------------------+------+

=== using a UDF ===
+--------------------+------+----+
|                 _c0|   _c1|abbr|
+--------------------+------+----+
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US| SEA|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US| MIA|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US| SFO|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US| MIA|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US| MIA|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US| SFO|
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US| SEA|
+--------------------+------+----+

=== df_abbrs ===
+--------------------+---+
|                 _c0|_c1|
+--------------------+---+
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...|SEA|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...|MIA|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...|SFO|
+--------------------+---+

=== using a join ===
+--------------------+------+---+
|                 _c0|   _c1|_c1|
+--------------------+------+---+
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US|SEA|
|SEATTLE TACOMA AI...| WA US|SEA|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US|SFO|
|SAN FRANCISCO INT...| CA US|SFO|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|MIA|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|MIA|
|MIAMI INTERNATION...| FL US|MIA|
+--------------------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column in dataframe and it will create new dataframe
You can use *dataframe.withColumn(newcolumnname, case statement to decode name to abbreviations)*