# Pyspark - create a single dictionary from two key list adding defined value for the list

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
list1 = ['SO', 'AE', 'AP']
list2 = ['NM', 'NV', 'OR']
```

I want to create a dictionary from this with adding defined values for each list so it should be:

```
list1's value = 'Midwest'
list2's value = 'Northeast'

map = {
 'SO': 'Midwest',
 'AE': 'Midwest',
 'AP': 'Midwest',
 'NM': 'Northeast',
 'NV': 'Northeast',
 'OR': 'Northeast',
}
```

I'm new to PySpark, not able to figure out how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Is this just a Python problem rather than spark? I don't see any dataframes

Comment: @mck I'm working on Pyspark, so need to create a dictionary from different lists which I'm further using to map values in a data frame from this dictionary using pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. This has nothing to do with Spark though.

```py
>>> list1 = ['SO', 'AE', 'AP']
>>> list2 = ['NM', 'NV', 'OR']
>>> dict1 = {k: "Midwest" for k in list1}
>>> dict1
{'SO': 'Midwest', 'AE': 'Midwest', 'AP': 'Midwest'}
>>> dict2 = {k: "Northeast" for k in list2}
>>> dict2
{'NM': 'Northeast', 'NV': 'Northeast', 'OR': 'Northeast'}
>>> dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}
>>> dict3
{'SO': 'Midwest',
 'AE': 'Midwest',
 'AP': 'Midwest',
 'NM': 'Northeast',
 'NV': 'Northeast',
 'OR': 'Northeast'}
```

Alternatively, if line `dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}` is giving you a `SyntaxError` (meaning you're using some pretty old Python, i.e. <3.5 or 2.x which is no longer supported), you can merge the dicts like this:

```py
>>> dict3 = dict1.copy()
>>> dict3.update(dict2)
>>> dict3
{'AP': 'Midwest',
 'SO': 'Midwest',
 'NM': 'Northeast',
 'AE': 'Midwest',
 'OR': 'Northeast',
 'NV': 'Northeast'}
```

Comment: Thanks @Czaporka, as working on PySpark still struggling on how to merge these two dictionary, any suggestions.

Comment: @SkyMonster the code samples you posted are pure Python, so I gave you a pure Python solution. This will also work perfectly fine in PySpark, except it doesn't use Spark's parallel computation capabilities, so it's not suitable for huge amounts of data. In order to leverage Spark you'll need to operate on RDDs / DataFrames instead of `dict`s and `list`s.

Comment: @SkyMonster I guess you already have some DataFrame somewhere and just want to use this `dict` as a mapping for appending a new column, e.g. "region"? In this case it does sound reasonable to store it as a `dict`. Recently I answered a question about a similar use case, maybe you'll find it useful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64651551/14222267).

Comment: Yes, I have created a udf to create a new column in the table:

`region_map` is my final dict,,,,,,

`user_func =  udf (lambda x: region_map.get(x), StringType())
df= df.withColumn('region',user_func(df.state_name))`

But the point is I have to make the final dictionary to make it work based on runtime values for each dictionary, (dict value are not pre-defined)

Comment: Ok in this case you'll have to add some more code to your question, showing where the runtime values come from, and explain what exactly is your problem because the way the question is formulated right now, my answer pretty much exhausts the topic.

Comment: yes, that's right. Problem is now just the merging part of these lists,(list are created dynamically, just need to merge them) if that can be resolved somehow, will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Hmm sorry but I'm getting increasingly confused about what you actually want to achieve. In my answer, the final dict `dict3` is the result of a merge of `dict1` with `dict2` and contains exactly the elements you specified as the expected output. What is wrong with it?

Comment: my bad,  `dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}` - this is not working in Pyspark

Comment: @SkyMonster Ok thanks for specifying the line that wasn't working. In the future please at least mention the exception you're getting and on which line. "The code doesn't work" doesn't say anything. But in this case I figured out that you're probably using a version of Python that doesn't support this syntax (again, this doesn't have much to do with whether it's PySpark or pure Python). You can check the version of your interpreter e.g. by executing `import sys; print(sys.version)`. Latest version is 3.9. Anyway, I have updated the answer with an alternative solution that should work.